# Finding polygon within polygon using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, select-by-location

How do I find two parks (shapefile) that are within a census tract ?

If I'm not mistaken you have to use selection by location.. but beyond that quite sure what to do after.

Comment: what version of ArcGIS? do you have census tracts? elaborate on what you have tried.

Comment: I have version 10.2.2 and yes I have my census tracts, I tried having the parks as the source layer, and intersect. I was thinking of joining them but they have no related field

Comment: Can't check for the exact wording right now, but it would not be *intersect* but something like *contains* or *within*.

Comment: You are correct in using Select By Location. You want to select Parks that intersect* Census Tracts *you may want to use completely within, centroid in, or some other selection criteria, depending on your needs. If you're just searching one census tract, select that tract and check the Use Selected Features in the Select By Location box. That will limit selection to just the selected tract(s). If there are more than two parks in the tract and you just want those two, you can set a definition query on the parks to just display those. No join needed, although you can do a spatial join as well.

Comment: recurvate post this as an answer and I will add a screen shot for you.